# How to define a winding number for a 2-torus in a 3-torus?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, geometric-topology

One can define two winding numbers for a 1D path on a 2-torus. They can be easily visualized on the "doughnut" representation (cf [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7MPf.png)):

[image]

A 2-torus can also be visualized as a square with periodic conditions, and we can define the same windings as how many times a curve crosses the horizontal or vertical boundaries ([cf this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlC2u.png)):

[image]

I am now wondering how one can generalize this to a "winding" number for a 2-torus in a 3-torus. We can start by visualizing the 3-torus as a cube, now identifying opposite edges as the same.
Then I can think of three ways different ways of embedding a 2-torus in this 3-torus,  [cf this sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PoFZs.png):

[image]

All the 2-torus in blue seem topologically equivalent when considered alone, but I guess that they are not when embedded in a 3-torus?
Are you aware of a proper way to classify these 2-torus inside 3-torus?

Some starting point may be that the "doughnut" like on the left does not reach the boundaries of the 3-torus, where the "cylinder" crosses it once and the "plane" crosses it twice?
But then what about a "tilted cylinder" like [this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jklHj.png):

[image]

It crosses two boundaries but seems different than a "plane".

I know this is not very rigorous, but any help or direction would be very much appreciated!

Comment: So one thing that seems clear is that we can take the two generators for $H_1(T)$ and regard them as elements of your 3D torus' first homology. In this setting, it seems like you're asking if a) every torus is represented by a class in $H_2((\mathbb{S}^1)^3)$ and if there is some convenient description of this homology group analogous to a winding number. The latter question has an affirmative answer, by the Kunneth formula of algebraic topology. One case of this formula says that the (integral) homology satisfies a binomial formula, so we can see that... (1/2)

Comment: $H^2((\mathbb{S}^1)^3) \simeq \mathbb{Z}^3$, so if there is such a thing, it will not be represented by a rational number, like the slope of a loop on a torus, but by a triple of numbers.